# Is runFullTrust mode in UWP app ,capable of broadFileAccess by default?

Tags: c#, file, uwp, file-permissions, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP app that requires the restricted capability "broadFileAccess" to access data from a file. I also have to use "runFullTrust" capability for registry access. My understanding  was that an app in "runFullTrust" mode had both file and registry access permissions and that "runFullTrust" is a higher level capability.

Problem:
 I tried giving "runFullTrust" capability,but for some reason the file access permissions are denied and also I dont even have an option to enable it under Settings for the app.
I also tried giving both the permissions,also then I got the File access denied error.

Question: 
Can I give "runFullTrust" capability to the app ,and will it automatically  inherit "broadFileAccess: capability? Or is it something  I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derive from official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations),

> The runFullTrust restricted capability allows apps to run at the full trust permission level on the user’s machine. This capability is required to use the `FullTrustProcessLauncher` API.
>
> This capability is also required for any desktop application that is delivered as an appx or msix package (as with the Desktop Bridge), and it will automatically appear in your manifest when packaging these apps using the Desktop App Converter (DAC) or Visual Studio.

The `broadFileSystemAccess` capability allows apps to get the same access to the file system as the user who is currently running the app without any additional file-picker style prompts during runtime. This capability works for the Windows.Storage APIs. Because users can grant or deny the permission any time in Settings, So if you have add this capability you also need to check the option in the setting page.

*Access is configurable in Settings > Privacy > File system.*

[image]

Comment: Thank you Nico Zhu. The problem is when the app is in FullTrust mode I dont have an option to configure permissions  in Settings > Privacy > File system.

Comment: You need add the  `broadFileSystemAccess` capability, the  configure permissions will display

Comment: Please check file access [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

Comment: Note the File System page doesn't refresh automatically you have to navigate somewhere else and come back to see the application appear. That being said, I still get access denied errors when trying to call StorageProviderSyncRootManager.GetCurrentSyncRoots. Does this requires something else than broadFileSystemAccess (and runFullTrust)?

Comment: Did you manage to get `StorageProviderSyncRootManager.GetCurrentSyncRoots` working, @SimonMourier?
Documentation is lacking, and it's hard to find information about it online. Hopefully you've been more lucky than me.

Comment: @Phenome - nope. I've abandoned UWP so far as it has too many various design issues.