# How to access WDMyCloud in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I am making an app that will access my *WDMyCloud* and get a list of music video files from a folder where they are stored. And I get **Access is denied** when I compile the file for store and side install, but while debugging the file does work fine, only when compile for side install is the issue. My WDMyCloud has a static address **\192.168.1.4** and the folder that I am trying to access is *\Video\Music Video*. In the *WDMyCloud* that folder is setup as public. In visual Studio I declared  in capabilities Private Networks. The code that I am using is `Directory.GetFiles(@"\\192.168.1.4\Video\Music Video\");` and if I run code in debugging it works fine. But when I compile the code for Store and side install I get the error for Access is denied. I have check around in the internet but found nothing that would work. I am thinking maybe there is a way to access it using the user name and password. In windows I have the credential already setup and saved with that information. Please if anyone have idea how to access *WDMyCloud* in *UWP* would be very helpful.

Comment: Please ensure you read the tag information before using tags so that you don't inadvertently misuse any. The `visual-studio` tag is only intended for questions related to the Visual Studio application, and not code written with it.

Comment: [Debug it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/debugging-net-native-windows-universal-apps/) and find where you get this error and read exception message.

Comment: debugging it works fine. The issue is when compiling for side load I get the error Access denied.

Comment: @AlB Have you added  [`broadFileSystemAccess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) capability for the app ?

Comment: Doing filesystemaccess now i get the error System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))' still not access to my cloud

Comment: @AlB, After add `broadFileSystemAccess` capability you need also switch on the app's permission in Setting page. Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55720859/7254781).

Comment: I add xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp uap5 rescap"> and  <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" /> and in file system I turn it on and I still can not access WDMyCloud. is there a login to access it for net work cloud?

Comment: @AlB you need if  *WDMyCloud* has restriction of access.

Comment: in WDMycloud I have set the folder as public. And the weird thing if I am debugging the program works perfect. But when I compile it for store and install it the access is denied and in  Capabilities has checked private networks and in file system the program has checked on. I really do not know why in debugging does not and in release form does not work. Does any one have other Ideas?

Comment: I was able to have the program to work with <Capabilities>
<rescap:Capability Name="developmentModeNetwork" />
</Capabilities> from the web link [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appinstaller/2017/06/09/uwp-apps-with-network-share-access/](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appinstaller/2017/06/09/uwp-apps-with-network-share-access/) And thanks to every one that gave some hint in this